# Como faço para colocar minha lista em ordem alfabética?

Tags: java, android, listview

Tenho uma `ListView` e gostaria de colocar em ordem alfabética pelos nomes dos clientes. Peço encarecidamente para serem o mais específicos possível pois não tenho muita experiência.

```
  import static android.R.id.list;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import br.gestaoBd.BancoDeDados.ClienteDao;
  import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Cliente;
  import br.gestaoBd.listaadapters.ClienteAdapter;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Collections;


  public class ListClientes extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView lista;
ArrayList<Cliente> clientes;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_clientes);

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    lista.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    atualizar(null);
}

public void atualizar(View view) {
    ClienteDao cliDao = new ClienteDao();

    clientes = cliDao.getListagem();
    lista.setAdapter(new ClienteAdapter(getBaseContext(), clientes));

}

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent cadClienteIntent = new Intent(this, CadCliente.class);
    cadClienteIntent.putExtra("Cliente", clientes.get(position));
    startActivity(cadClienteIntent);
    return true;
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
    Intent cadPedidoIntent = new Intent(this, CadPedido.class);
    cadPedidoIntent.putExtra("Cliente", clientes.get(position));
    startActivity(cadPedidoIntent);

}

}
```

Meu Cliente adapter:

```
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Cliente;
  import br.gestaoBd.Mask;
  import br.gestaoBd.R;
  import java.util.List;

  public class ClienteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  

private Context context;
private List<Cliente> clientes;

public ClienteAdapter(Context context, List<Cliente> clientes) {
    this.context = context;
    this.clientes = clientes;
}

public int getCount() {
    return clientes.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return clientes.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return clientes.get(position).getId();
}  


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Cliente cliente = clientes.get(position);

    LayoutInflater layout = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = layout.inflate(R.layout.linhacli, null);

    Log.i("AULA", "Montou:" + cliente.getNome());
    Log.e("ERRO", "Valor da variavel estava nullo!");

    ImageView imgImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imgImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sem_foto);

    TextView edNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    edNome.setText(cliente.getNome());

    TextView lblTelefone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    lblTelefone.setText(cliente.getTelefone());


    return view;
}
}
```

minha lista

```
 import static android.R.id.list;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import br.gestaoBd.BancoDeDados.ClienteDao;
 import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Cliente;
 import br.gestaoBd.listaadapters.ClienteAdapter;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collections;


 public class ListClientes extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView lista;
ArrayList<Cliente> clientes;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_clientes);

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    lista.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    atualizar(null);
}

public void atualizar(View view) {
    ClienteDao cliDao = new ClienteDao();

    clientes = cliDao.getListagem();
    lista.setAdapter(new ClienteAdapter(getBaseContext(), clientes));

}

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent cadClienteIntent = new Intent(this, CadCliente.class);
    cadClienteIntent.putExtra("Cliente", clientes.get(position));
    startActivity(cadClienteIntent);
    return true;
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
    Intent cadPedidoIntent = new Intent(this, CadPedido.class);
    cadPedidoIntent.putExtra("Cliente", clientes.get(position));
    startActivity(cadPedidoIntent);


}

}
```

Comment: Não seria mais fácil ordenar seu ArrayList de Clientes e já mandar eles organizado? Pode fazer isso usando Comparator, veja essa resposta no [**SOEn**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2784576/5524514)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para ordenar a lista vamos utilizar o método `sort` da classe `Collections`.

Este método pede dois parâmetros:

1. A lista que será ordenada.
2. A interface `Comparator`, que terá a lógica de ordenação.

Para implementar esta interface, temos que informar o tipo de objeto que vamos trabalhar, neste caso o `Cliente`.

```
new Comparator<Cliente>()
```

Este objeto deve ser do mesmo tipo do informado na Lista.

Para comparar `String`, utilizamos o método `compareTo`.

Isto porque String implementa [Comparable](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Para comparar `int` , seguimos a seguinte lógica:

Se o primeiro inteiro for menor que o segundo, retornamos -1 (ou qualquer negativo).

Se o primeiro inteiro for maior que o segundo, retornamos 1 (ou qualquer positivo).

Se são iguais, então retornamos 0.

Seu código deve se parecer com isto:

```
 clientes = cliDao.getListagem();
    Collections.sort(clientes, new Comparator<Cliente>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Cliente o1, Cliente o2) {
                return o1.getNome()).compareTo(o2.getNome());
            }

        });

 lista.setAdapter(new ClienteAdapter(getBaseContext(), clientes));
```

Se você quer ordenar em várias partes do seu código esta lista, podemos implementar diretamente a interface `Comparable` no `Cliente`.

Assim não será necessário repetir o `Comparator`

Seria mais ou menos assim:

classe Cliente:

```
public class Cliente implements Comparable<Cliente>{

public int compareTo(Cliente outroCliente) {
      return o1.getNome()).compareTo(o2.getNome());
  }
}
```

Sua lista:

```
 clientes = cliDao.getListagem();
 Collections.sort(clientes);
 lista.setAdapter(new ClienteAdapter(getBaseContext(), clientes));
```

Outra forma seria seu método **getListagem()** do `DAO` já retornar ordenada através do [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp).

Qualquer dúvida, estamos à disposição!

Comment: Também acho que é mais simples ordenar o **`arraylist`**, só acho que sua resposta pecou em não explicar o que está sendo feito. O AP pediu "*encarecidamente para serem o mais específicos possível pois não tenho muita experiência*".

Comment: Você tem razão @renan ! Editei a resposta ! Obrigado pela dica!